# How to get called class or method/function name

Tags: php

Is there a way to get called function/method name in php ?
I want to know from which method my function is being called, Is there such a way to do that in PHP ?

you can consider below example to get more clear picture what i'm trying to achieve.

Example:

```
class abc {
    function fruit() {
        echo 'fruit method called';
        // can i get information from which method this method is being called 
        // SAMPLE OUTPUT
        // METHOD CALLED FROM fruit_nested_method -> fruit_another_nested_method
    }

    function fruit_nested_method() {
        echo $this->fruit();
    }

    function fruit_another_nested_method() {
        echo $this->fruit_nested_method();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php like this?

Comment: In each method echo the method name like `echo 'fruit_another_nested_method';`, by this way you will know

Comment: @developer : i have already code in place i can't do in each and every function i have common function for error_log for that i want to know from which method which class error is generated, hope it make more value to question :)

Comment: @RST : let me check your suggestion